# WordPress deprecated issue

Tags: wordpress, elementor

My website is showing this error:

Deprecated: WP_User_Query was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 5.9.0! who is deprecated. Use capability instead. in /home1/ssplubusinsescom/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5607

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Elementor\Scheme_Typography' not found in /home1/ssplubusinsescom/public_html/wp-content/plugins/tmc-posts/widgets/carousel.php:1132 Stack trace: #0 /home1/ssplubusinsescom/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/controls-stack.php(2280): Elementortmcposts\Widgets\tmc_PostCarousel->_register_controls() #1 /home1/ssplubusinsescom/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/controls-stack.php(494): Elementor\Controls_Stack->init_controls() #2 /home1/ssplubusinsescom/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/widget-base.php(177): Elementor\Controls_Stack->get_stack() #3 /home1/ssplubusinsescom/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/controls-stack.php(300): Elementor\Widget_Base->get_stack() #4 /home1/ssplubusinsescom/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/controls-stack.php(2369): Elementor\Controls_Stack->get_controls() #5 /home1/ssplubusinsescom/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/controls-stack.php in /home1/ssplubusinsescom/public_html/wp-content/plugins/tmc-posts/widgets/carousel.php on line 1132

Can you help me to make my website work again.

Thanks,
Abdullah

Comment: Can you post the code that is causing this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, Jay

Currently, the homepage is blank cuz is created through elementor builder, I know the the elementor is causing the issue. Can you help me to fix this?

https://businessplus.com.pk/

Comment: And when I enable debug its show this error on HomePage only and

Deprecated: WP_User_Query was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 5.9.0! who is deprecated. Use capability instead. in /home1/ssplubusinsescom/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5607

Comment: fyi probably best to post to wordpress.stackexchange.com, not here (this isn't a programming question). When you repost there, be sure to include all needed details in your question.

Comment: Okay, Thanks Sir

Answer (score 0):

Just update the all yours plugin to the latest version especially Elementor, the issue will get fixed.

if its not resolve, try the below steps.

This may be a plugin or theme conflict. Please attempt to disable all plugins, and use one of the default (Twenty*) themes. If the problem goes away, enable them one by one to identify the source of your troubles.

If you can install plugins, install “Health Check”: https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/ On the troubleshooting tab, you can click the button to disable all plugins and change the theme for you, while you’re still logged in, without affecting normal visitors to your site. You can then use its admin bar menu to turn on/off plugins and themes one at a time.